# Robots.txt Disallow file - should this be left empty?

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, robots.txt

Need help on this robots.txt question. My default file looks something like this

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: https://mywebsite.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

Problem is that with this configuration, Google deindexed almost all (at the time of this writing) of my URLs.

Is it correct to leave the disallow field blank?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's technically correct.

This means that all user agents, including search engines, can access to your website pages.

The asterisk near user-agent means that it applies to all user agents.

Nothing is listed after disallow, this means there are no restrictions at all.

Comment: I see. I just find this weird that my pages are marked No: 'noindex' detected in 'robots' meta tag. There's no noindex that I implemented on each page, so I assumed that the culprit is the robots.txt file

Comment: Are you using any seo plugin?
It could be related to some kind of configuration.

Comment: Yes, Yoast. But the noindex should still reflect in the page source right?

Comment: Sure, in the page <head>.